# ACL (Access Control List) Codeigniter by User ID not by Roles

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, acl

I tried to create ACL (access control list) but per user id, not by role 
because the client wants that same **level** but has different **permission**

how I can check if the user accessing a method or controller that don't have permission in database

here is table **permissions** structure

```
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| permission_id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| permission_name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| permission_desc        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| permission_created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| permission_modified_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

then, **permissions** table has relation with **permission_role** table
and here is **permission_role**'s structure

```
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| permission_role_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id            | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| permission_id      | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

now, I am confused if the user accesses a controller that the user doesn't have permissions to access it, how I can check it?  if check by route or URI but my database didn't save class controller ...
Any solution please ?

Thank you, and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Can you show data of `permissions` table?

Comment: @Yogendrasinh here it is : https://postimg.cc/zbVkWn4M and here **permission role** data : https://postimg.cc/bdqb2X2n

Comment: As per your `permissions` table column `permission_name` contain the module name with it's method in bracket. What about your controller name.
What is your controller name and method name for Department(View)?

Comment: so, we check the permission through URI ? and calling one by one on method ?

Comment: Can you tell us what is your controller name and method name for the `Department (view)` in your database?

Comment: @Yogendrasinh the controller name is `Master`, and method for view is `departement` and in my database just save `permission_name` ...

Comment: I don't know whether it will help you or not.
First you can get all the permission id with matching method name like below.
`select permission_id from permissions where permission_name like % department %`
After that you can check if the current login user and the permission array matched records in permission_role table as below.
`select permission_role_id from permission_role where user_id = current_login_user_id and permission_id in ('all permission id that were fetched');`
If second query result is true then allow user to perform operation else show error.

Comment: the easiest way would have been to store the controller and method in the `permissions` table, then with a `MY_Controller` you could check if the user has permission using the `router` class which will contain the current controller and method. your design is flawed and you should refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Branch` .etc. is the controller and `view`, `edit` are methods with your storage system you would have to do:

```
class Branch extends CI_Controller {

     public function view {
         $this->acl->can_access(6);
     }

     public function edit {
         $this->acl->can_access(9);
     }
}
```

Acl Model:

```
class Acl extends CI_Model {

     public function can_access($permission_id = null) {
         $uid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
         if (!is_null($uid) && !is_null($permission_id)) {
             $this->db->where('user_id', $uid);
             $this->db->where('permission_id', $permission_id);
             $this->db->from('permissions_role');
             if ($this->db->count_all_results() > 0) {
                 return;
             }
         }
         show_error('Not allowed'); // function exits
     }

}
```

If you refactored your db structure to contain both your controller/method in the `permission` table you wouldn't have to include `can_access` in every auth method and could just have your controllers extend a `MY_Controller` with code that looks like:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->can_access();
    }

    private function can_access() {
        $controller = $this->router->class;
        $method = $this->router->method;
        $curr_user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        // do join between permissions and permissions role...
        // check if num_rows > 0 for current user given the controller/method
        // if num_rows is not greater than 0 (user doesn't have permission)
        // then show error. otherwise do nothing (user has permission)
    }

}
```